# How to resolve value for "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}"

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode, gwt-dev-mode

I am new to gwt I have created a web application and i am able to work on super dev mode. but while i am trying to automate the process of invoking the code server and web application i am facing issue. My scenario is i have an main class where i am invoking the **DevMode** class by giving the hard coded arguments

```
String remoteUI="\"${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}\"";
System.out.println("remote url:"+remoteUI);
String startupurl=""applicationClassName.html";
String codeServerPort="9997";
String port="8888";
String module=packageName;
String devModeargs[]={"-war",warLocation,"-startupUrl",startupurl,-logLevel","INFO","-codeServerPort",codeServerPort,"-port",port,module };
    /**
     * invoking dev mode main class
     */
  DevMode.main(devModeargs);
```

Here the remoteui values are resolved if i give this as program arguments in eclipse. if i give directly inside the program it is considering as strings.

How to resolve the remote ui value at runtime.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't, those placeholders are resolved by Eclipse before calling the main class with the resolved values.

You may not actually need them though: they're here so that DevMode doesn't show its own UI but instead connect to this gist and port (where Eclipse listens) to use the Eclipse view as UI. If you don't pass them, then DevMode will use its own UI.